# Stop animation of first div when second is started

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, queue

I want to create animated hover. On `mouseover` I need to fadeOut div, then change its content background and color, and show it again. And on `mouseout` put everything in the previous condition.
My HTML is

```
<div class="icon-wrapper">
    <span class="icon like-icon"></span>
     like 
</div>
<div class="icon-wrapper">
   <span class="icon comment-icon"></span>
   comment 
</div>
```

and my javaScript code

```
$('.icon-wrapper').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity:0}{queue:true,duration:1000,complete:function() {
        $(this).find('.icon').css('backgroundPositionY','-56px');
        $(this).css('color','#dd3939');
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},{queue:true,duration:1000});
     }});
  },function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity:0},{queue:true,duration:1000,complete :function() {
        $(this).find('.icon').css('backgroundPositionY','-12px');
        $(this).css('color','#707173');
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},{queue:true,duration:1000});
  }});
});
```

I get almost what I need. The only thing is that I want to stop animation of first div when I'm starting the animation of second.

Comment: you can stop animating first and animate it again like $(this).stop().animate();.

Comment: @Danis i can't understand where is the animation of second div sorry? can you show the div 1 animation and the div2 animation?

Comment: @Danis any chance of getting a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your code. That way we can see it at work and it will make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

To stop animations just use

```
$(this).stop( true, true );
```

But when it comes to the styling it probably makes more sense to use a css class

When you hover use

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

When you exit the element

```
$(this).removeClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need some refactoring, why do you use to animate opacity when you have `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods available? check this:

```
$('.icon-wrapper').on('mouseover',
    function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000,function() {
        $(this).find('.icon').css('backgroundPositionY','-56px');
        $(this).css('color','#dd3939');
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
     });
  },function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000,function() {
        $(this).find('.icon').css('backgroundPositionY','-12px');
        $(this).css('color','#707173');
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

then you can use `stop();` to stop events, and i hope your using `clone();` for replacing html content :)

Comment: Can I ask, why I have to use clone()?

Comment: oh maybe i bad red your question in some points , clone() is to copy and paste elements in general if you need to copy and paste you can use that

Comment: can you show where you need to stop the animation man? so i can help you at all